# Pasar datos de textbox a una tabla IOS 10 Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, uitableview

Necesito pasar datos a una tabla en otra pantalla, en este caso vehículo, detalle de chequeo.

el vehículo como titulo y el detalle como subtitulo en la primera tabla
y así mismo las opciones seleccionadas en la tabla se debería asignar al vehículo y mostrarlos en la pantalla de abajo
en la vista de abajo en teoría debería ir una tabla que muestre las opciones seleccionadas para cada auto en la pantalla anterior

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: puedes poner algo de codigo que tengas?

Answer (score 0):

Es una descripción un poco escasa de lo que quieres, pero si lo he entendido bien básicamente necesitarías tener un protocolo:

```
protocol AddCarProtocol: class {
   func didSaveNewCar(car: Car)
}
```

y una variable `weak var delegate: AddCarProtocol?` que tendría tu controlador para añadir coches y que setearías desde el controlador que muestra el listado de coches, en `prepareForSegue` si usas `segues`.

Podrías definir una estructura `Car` para contener la información de un coche:

```
struct Car {
    var name: String
    var checkDetail: String
    var checkPoints: [String]
}
```

Así en tu controlador para añadir coches, podrías tener un array con posibles puntos de chequeo:

`let availableCheckPoints = ["Alineacion", "Balanceo", "Cambio aceite", "Mantenimiento A/C"]`

así tu método para guardar el coche:

```
@IBAction func doSaveCar(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let carName = self.tfCar.text, let checkDetail = self.tfDetail.text else {
        return
    }
    let checkPoints = self.getSelectedCheckPoints()
    let car = Car(name: carName, checkDetail: checkDetail, checkPoints: checkPoints)
    self.delegate?.didSaveNewCar(car: car)
    _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}

private func getSelectedCheckPoints() -> [String] {
    if let selectedIndexPaths = self.tableview.indexPathsForSelectedRows {

        var selectedCheckpoints: [String] = []
        selectedIndexPaths.forEach({ (indexPath) in
            selectedCheckpoints.append(self.availableCheckPoints[indexPath.row])
        })
        return selectedCheckpoints
    }
    return []
}
```

Así en tu viewController del listado de coches, tendrías el método delegado:

```
extension ViewController: AddCarProtocol {
   func didSaveNewCar(car: Car) {
      self.cars.append(car)
      self.tableview.reloadData()
   }
}
```

y por último para pasar al controlador que muestra los detalles de un coche:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showCarDetailsVC", sender: self.cars[indexPath.row])
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showAddCarViewController" {
        let vc = segue.destination as? AddCarViewController
        vc?.delegate = self
    }
    else if segue.identifier == "showCarDetailsVC" {
        let vc = segue.destination as? CarDetailViewController
        vc?.car = sender as? Car
    }
}
```

y tendrías disponibles los datos del coche seleccionado, para mostrarlos en el controlador en `viewDidLoad` por ejemplo.